# Transferring ownership of an iPhone app with Apple Pay

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, applepay, app-store-connect

I am trying to transfer an app to a different developer account . During the transfer process I am encountering an error stating app containing passbook entitlements.

App does not contain any functionality related to passbook but uses Apple Pay .

What are the passbook entitlements ? Are they referring to entitlements generated by Apple Pay ? (com.apple.developer.in-app-payments)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the official requirements for app transfers over at https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devaf27784ff

Specially the app is **not** allowed to have:

- No version of the app can use a Passbook entitlement.

To check the entitlements of your app follow https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1798/_index.html